# Using strtok, works for one file but not another

Tags: c

Here is my code:

```
      char delims[4];
      delims[0]='\t';
      delims[1]=' ';
      delims[2]=',';
      delims[3]='\0';

      i = 0;
      while (fgets(line, 10000, fp) != NULL) 
      { 

        result = strtok(line,delims);

        while(result != NULL) {
          (*data_array)[i++] = atof(result);
          result = strtok(NULL, delims);
        }
      }
```

Straightforward enough.  And it works perfectly for the following file:

```
      3.600000 79.000000
      1.800000 54.000000
      3.333000 74.000000
      2.283000 62.000000
      4.533000 85.000000
      2.883000 55.000000
      4.700000 88.000000
```

But it doesn't work for this file:

```
      3.6   79  3
      1.8   54  3
      3.333 74  3
      2.283 62  1
      4.533 85  1
      2.883 55  1
      4.7   88  2
      3.6   85  1
      1.95  51  1
      4.35  85  3
```

And I get an "Aborted (core dumped)" error.  What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Here's the whole function.  *data_array and *data_labels were just declared in main().  I commented out some of the data_labels part just so I could get the first part working:

```
    int getdata(double* *data_array, int* *data_labels, int argc, char *argv[], int *items, int *attr)
    {  
      // filename variables
      char *filename;         // pointer to a string that will contain the name of the training data file.
      char *result = NULL;    // used with strtok() to extract each feature value given a line of delimited features.
      FILE *fp;               // pointer to FILE, we can use this with fgets to access each line
      char line[10000];       // array of 1000 chars for storing the raw data for one observation
      char delims[4];         // an array of common delimiters for data files
      delims[0]='\t';
      delims[1]=' ';
      delims[2]=',';
      delims[3]='\0';

      int i, j;

      // check that we have the correct number of command line arguments
      if (argc < 2)
      {
        printf("2usage: progname filename\n");
        return -1;
      }

      if (argc < 4)
      {
        printf("3usage: progname filename num_labels k(nn)\n");
        return -1;
      }

      if (atoi(argv[2]) < 1)
      {
        printf("num_labels must be a positive integer.\n");
        return -1;
      }

      if (atof(argv[2]) - atoi(argv[2]) > 0)
      {
        printf("num_labels must be an integer.\n");
        return -1;
      }

       if (atoi(argv[3]) < 1)
      {
        printf("k must be a positive integer.\n");
        return -1;
      }

      if (atof(argv[3]) - atoi(argv[3]) > 0)
      {
        printf("k must be an integer.\n");
        return -1;
      }

      // try to open the file
      filename = argv[1];
      fp = fopen(filename, "r");
      if (fp == NULL)
      {
        printf("could not open file: %s\n", filename);
        printf("note: the filename should be the second command line argument, after the .exe file");
        return -1;
      }

      printf("reading file: %s\n", filename);

      // get first line of the file to get num_items and num_attrs.
      fgets(line, 1000, fp);
      sscanf(line, "%d \t %d", items, attr);
      printf("num items: %d\n", *items);
      printf("num attributes: %d\n", *attr);  

      if (atoi(argv[3]) > *items)
      {
        printf("k should be smaller than the number of items in the input file.\n");
        return -1;
      }

      // create an array of the data
      *data_array = malloc(*items* *attr*sizeof(double));
      *data_labels = malloc(*items*sizeof(int));
      printf("data array size = %d\n\n",*items* *attr);

      i=0;
      j=0;

      while (fgets(line, 10000, fp) != NULL) 
      { 

        // we break line into tokens using our delimeters list declared at the beginning of the function
        result = strtok(line,delims);
        //printf("%d\n",i);

        while(result != NULL) {
          (*data_array)[i++] = atof(result);
          //printf("%f\n",(*data_array)[i-1]);
          result = strtok(NULL, delims);
        }
        //(*data_labels)[j++] = (int)((*data_array)[--i]);
      }
      /*
      printf("j=%d,items=%d\n",j,*items);
      for (i=0;i<*items;i++)
      {
        printf("i=%d,items=%d,",i,*items);
        printf("label=%d\n",(*data_labels)[i]);
      }
      // close the file
      fclose(fp);

      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: What is the type of `*data_array)` and size?

Comment: Post a small, complete, compilable program that demonstrates the problem.  One possibility is that your `data_array` isn't properly sized, but that can't really be known from what you've posted.

Comment: I removed my answer because what I had guess was wrong your expression `(*data_array)[i++] = atof(result);` is correct you may have length issue. that is buffer overrun to avoid this add a check `i < (*items* *attr*sizeof(double)`) before assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of elements `(*data_array)` can hold is less that the number of tokens you're trying to fill in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your call of `strtok` is allright - I would replace initialization of `delims` with the equivalent

```
char *delims = "\t ,";
```

and switched to a re-enterable [`strtok_r`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok_r), but that's not what causing the crash (unless you are in a concurrent environment, in which case the crash should be random and mostly independent of the file being parsed).

This line is highly suspicious:

```
(*data_array)[i++] = atof(result);
```

You either do not have enough space allocated to the array pointed to by the `data_array` pointer, or the `data_array` itself is invalid.